# Print file names which is in directory and have more than 54 words

Tags: linux, shell, find

I need to find all files who have more than 54 words which are in directory "secret" which can be anywhere.

I started with:

```
find / | grep 'secret/*'
```

Comment: You can use regular expressions with `grep`, including numerical quantifiers as in "\{x,y\} match x to y occurrences of the preceding.".

Comment: Thanks for answer. But can I get an example? Cause it's confusing a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
find / -type f | grep 'secret/*' | awk /[a-zA-Z.-]{54}/
```

use whatever pattern matching that you like in awk /[your pattern]/